# Export / import Eclipse cdt make targets

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-cdt

I'm heavily relying on make targets in my Eclipse cdt projects, and have 50+ make targets defined.

Is there a possibility to export and import them into another project?

I can't find any GUI way to do this from within Eclipse, but perhaps I'm just looking over the obvious, or perhaps there is a way to accomplish this by editing the configuration files directly?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

look at the .cproject file at the top of your workspace you should see something like this in the file.  Try a cut and paste of these blocks into you other project.

```
<storageModule moduleId="org.eclipse.cdt.make.core.buildtargets">
    <buildTargets>
        <target name="all" path="directory1/directory2/directory3" targetID="org.eclipse.cdt.build.MakeTargetBuilder">
            <buildCommand>make</buildCommand>
            <buildArguments/>
            <buildTarget>all</buildTarget>
            <stopOnError>true</stopOnError>
            <useDefaultCommand>false</useDefaultCommand>
            <runAllBuilders>true</runAllBuilders>
        </target>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can directly copy the "Make targets" (CTL+C) and Paste it (CTL+V) under the good repository in the Make target view